# opencv library video play

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to play video

How can it be done using opencv ?

Comment: Paste the code you have written so far so we can help you fix it.

Comment: By the way, if you don't want anything displayed in OpenCV's native window, you should remove all calls to `cvNamedWindow()`, `cvShowImage()` and `cvDestroyWindow()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the code from [our previous conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770579/176769) to build a **minimal example that shows how to retrieve frames from the camera and display them inside a `QLabel`**.

Notice that the value passed to `cvCreateCameraCapture()` can change on your system. On my Linux `0` is the magic number. On Windows and Mac I use `-1`.

For simplicity purposes, I'm just sharing the body of the `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0); // try -1 or values > 0 if your camera doesn't work
    if (!capture)
    {   
        std::cout << "Failed to create capture";
        return -1; 
    }   

    IplImage* frame = NULL;
    QLabel label;
    while (1) 
    {   
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if( !frame ) break;

        QImage qt_img = IplImage2QImage(frame);
        label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_img));
        label.show();

        // calling cvWaitKey() is essencial to create some delay between grabbing frames
        cvWaitKey(10); // wait 10ms
    }   

    return app.exec();
}
```

**EDIT:**

The procedure to play a video file or video from a camera are the same. The only thing that really changes is `cvCreateCameraCapture()` for `cvCreateFileCapture()`.

If `cvCreateFileCapture()` is returning `NULL`, it means that it couldn't open the video file. This could happen for 2 reasons: it doesn't have the codec to deal with the video, or it couldn't find the file.

A lot of people make the folowwing mistake on Windows when loading files:

```
capture = cvCreateFileCapture("C:\path\video.avi");
```

They use single slashes, when they should be using double:

```
capture = cvCreateFileCapture("C:\\path\\video.avi");
```

and if something can fail, you **must ALWAYS check the return of the call**:

```
capture = cvCreateFileCapture("C:\\path\\video.avi");
if (!capture)
{
   // print error message, then exit
}
```