# GUI with Qt Creator to play video

Tags: c++, c, opencv, qt-creator

```
frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);

while(key!='q'){

    cvNamedWindow( "main",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("main", frame);
    if(frame!=NULL){

        drawSquares( frame, findSquares4( frame, storage ) );

        /* wait for key. Also the function cvWaitKey takes care of event processing */
        key = cvWaitKey(33);
        IplImage *img = cvCloneImage(frame);
        if (img->origin){
            cvFlip(img);
            img->origin= 0;
        }

        QImage* qimg = IplImageToQImage(img)
        // qimg = IplImage2QImage (img);
        QLabel label;
        ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimg));
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
```

I like to play video with Qt Creator. I use the code above, but it's not okay. I get the following error:

> IplImageToQImage was not declared in this scope

Does anyone know how I can play video with OpenCV and Qt Creator in the same window?

Comment: The question itself is very poor, but even so could you at the very least please try to format your code? You can see what it looks like at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to play video using opencv and qt creator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761158/how-to-play-video-using-opencv-and-qt-creator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it makes sense since `IplImage2QImage()` is not a part of Qt nor OpenCV.

You probably saw this function being used somewhere on the Internet and copied/pasted into your code.

With a simple search on Google I found [the implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811112634/http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Using_OpenCV_with_Qt) of this function:

```
static QImage IplImage2QImage(const IplImage *iplImage)
{
    int height = iplImage->height;
    int width = iplImage->width;
 
    if  (iplImage->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U && iplImage->nChannels == 3)
    {
      const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)iplImage->imageData;
      QImage img(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
      return img.rgbSwapped();
    } else if  (iplImage->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U && iplImage->nChannels == 1){
    const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)iplImage->imageData;
    QImage img(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
 
    QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i));
    }
    img.setColorTable(colorTable);
    return img;
    }else{
      qWarning() << "Image cannot be converted.";
      return QImage();
    }
}
```

Hopefully you'll know what to do with it.

I wrote this minimal example to show how to successfully use `IplImage2QImage()`. It uses `cvLoadImage()` to load a file named test.jpg from the disk and then displays it on a QLabel. It's simple, and it works!

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <QtGui>
#include <QImage>

static QImage IplImage2QImage(const IplImage *iplImage)
{
    int height = iplImage->height;
    int width = iplImage->width;

    if  (iplImage->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U && iplImage->nChannels == 3)
    {
      const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)iplImage->imageData;
      QImage img(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
      return img.rgbSwapped();
    }
    else if  (iplImage->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U && iplImage->nChannels == 1)
    {
        const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)iplImage->imageData;
        QImage img(qImageBuffer, width, height, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

        QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i));
        }
        img.setColorTable(colorTable);
        return img;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Image cannot be converted.";
      return QImage();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("test.jpg", 1);
    if (!img)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load test.jpg";
        return -1;
    }

    QImage qt_img = IplImage2QImage(img);

    QLabel label;
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_img));
    label.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

On my Linux box, I compiled it with:

```
g++ qimage.cpp -o qimage -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/qt_47x/include -I/opt/qt_47x/include/QtGui -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/qt_47x/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lQtCore -lQtGui
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i try with this function and it's not ok

Comment: *it's not ok* is not an accurate description of the problem you are facing.

Comment: I updated the answer with a fully functional minimal example, just to show you that the code I shared before **WORKS**! It would be nice of you to upvote helpful answers and select the answer that solved your problem. This last part you can do by clicking on the checkbox near the answer, to select it as the official answer to your question.

Comment: sorry but i try to display video and not  only an image so if you can please can you show me an print screen for the interface after playing video ?

Comment: The problem stated in your question was solved in my answer. The right thing to do is either upvote my answer if it helped you somehow, or accept it as the official answer to your question by clicking in the checkbox near the answer, or do both! **Don't hijack your own thread.** I noticed you already asked a question on how to play videos with OpenCV and Qt and I am considering to help you, but you should do one thing at a time.

Comment: I try to compile this code ,So i don't have error but i show nothing !!it's the problem

Comment: **The** problem is that you are not reading the code nor paying attention to my answer. You need to have a file named `test.jpg` in the same directory as the compiled application, do you have it? =)

Comment: sorry i don't undrestand you karlphillip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9102/discussion-between-karlphillip-and-darck)

Comment: sorry for my english realy i'm so sorry my officiel language is french and i dont speak english very good i hope that you undrestand my problem i try to add picture or print screen to my execute program but I have not the access